# How to add multiple SelectParameters to a SqlDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have been trying to add two SelectParameters to my SqlDataSource with no avail.

Below is my code in the aspx page

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>Search By child</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Case Number:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCaseNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSearchChild" runat="server">Search</asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<asp:GridView ID="childListGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="20" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="child_recordId" HeaderText="Child ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="child_recordId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="child_caseNumber" HeaderText="Case Number" SortExpression="child_caseNumber" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="child_LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="child_LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="child_FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="child_FirstName" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" " InsertVisible="False"
                SortExpression="child_recordId">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewForms" runat="server" CommandName="ViewForms" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("child_recordId") %>' OnClick="lnkViewForms_Click">View forms</asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
    </asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:eci_conn %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE [child_LastName] LIKE @lname + '%' AND [child_FirstName] LIKE @fname + '%' ORDER BY [child_LastName]">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="lname" DbType="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="fname" DbType="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And in my code behind I tried the following

```
    Dim lNameParam As New Parameter("@lname", DbType.String)
    Dim fNameParam As New Parameter("@fname", DbType.String)
    lNameParam.DefaultValue = txtLastName.Text.Trim()
    fNameParam.DefaultValue = txtFirstName.Text.Trim()
    SqlDataSource5.SelectParameters.Add(lNameParam)
    SqlDataSource5.SelectParameters.Add(fNameParam)
    childListGrid.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource5"
```

and also this

```
SqlDataSource5.SelectParameters.Add("@lname", txtLastName.Text.Trim())
SqlDataSource5.SelectParameters.Add("@fname", txtFirstName.Text.Trim())
childListGrid.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource5"
```

and this

```
SqlDataSource5.SelectParameters("lname").DefaultValue = txtLastName.Text.Trim()
SqlDataSource5.SelectParameters("fname").DefaultValue = txtFirstName.Text.Trim()
childListGrid.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource5"
```

Nothing seems to be working, what else can I try?

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it's not working?

Comment: Nothing gets returned. It works just fine with one parameter, but it is just not working with two. When I step thru the code I see that the count is 4 instead of two https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2956296/parameters.png

Answer (score 1):

You only need to do one or the other (markup or codebehind) when adding parameters to your SqlDataSource.  Take a look at this:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="lname" ControlID="txtLastName" PropertyName="Text" />
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="fname" ControlID="txtFirstName" PropertyName="Text" />
</SelectParameters>
```

At this point, both of your ControlParameters have been added to your SqlDataSource.  There is no need to add them again in codebehind.

Notice that I added the "ControlID" and "PropertyName" properties to the markup.  I'm not sure how you were getting by without them, but they are necessary for the parameter to work correctly.

Since you are changing datasources during your postback, you need to make sure and call databind after making that change:

```
childListGrid.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource5";
childListGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: I'm creating the GridView in the markup. I changed the markup to reflect the one you provided. If I do not need to add the parameters in the code behind, how do I perform the search? If I just leave `childListGrid.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource5"` in the code behind and then click in search it brings back everything. I added my GridView code to the question

Comment: @JGeZau Your DataSourceID in the markup is set to `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"`.  Shouldn't it be `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5"`?  I think maybe you have not explained your scenario fully, or I'm just not understanding something.

Comment: SqlDataSource1 is the "default" datasource. I have other ones for the search functionality. Once you first load the page, it loads with DS1; DS2 is to search by CaseNumber (as you can see I have a text box for this) and this is working perfect. I have DS3 and DS4 that search by Last Name and First Name respectively, this also works perfect because is using two DSs for first and last name. What I want to do is get rid of DS3 and DS4 and combine them to be able to search for fname and lname together, this is where I am having trouble

Comment: @JGeZau Ah, thank you for the additional information! I think I see what your problem is. In your first comment here, you said "*If I just leave childListGrid.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource5" in the code behind and then click in search it brings back everything*" - you need to call databind after you change the datasource ID, and then you should be good to go.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Hey, @JGeZau.  Did this answer solve your problem, or help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SqlDataSource5.SelectParameters("lname").DefaultValue = txtLastName.Text.Tostring
SqlDataSource5.SelectParameters("fname").DefaultValue = txtFirstName.Text.Tostring
childListGrid.DataSource = "SqlDataSource5"
childListGrid.Databind
```

Comment: where are you updating this code? is it in your page load? are you using an ajax call to update the reuslts if its not in your page load?

Comment: try adding a databind to your page load.
also did you test your query to make sure you are getting results back?

Comment: the query is working and also is works fine with one parameter, but stops working when I add two

Comment: I realy do not like when people on purpose write code with mistakes - in this case () instead []